# I need a css minifier in ruby

Tags: css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, minify

I am looking for a css minifier that I could use in rails apps (not gziper) which doesn't need a command line YUI compressor instalation.
I am working on a content mangament software where the css is pasted into a textarea and then I want to minify then gzip and send it to amazon.
So those solutions are not OK which use some command line preprocessing...
Any ideas?

Online minifier services are also welcome.

Comment: There is the Google Closure Compiler, but that isn't written in Ruby AFAICT...

Comment: Well... That is good to compress the javasript...

Comment: Oh, whoops. For some reason I misread CSS and thought JS. Disregard that comment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have found my gem:

```
'ruby-yui-compressor'
```

All I need to do:

```
gem "yui-compressor", "~> 0.9.6", :require => "yui/compressor"
....
compressor = YUI::CssCompressor.new
compressor.compress 'body {line-height: 1}            \ntable {border-collapse: collapse;    border-spacing: 0}'

=> "body{line-height:1}\\ntable{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}"
```

Answer (score 12):

You could also try [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#using_sass) with `:syntax => :scss, :style => :compressed`.

Comment: Since the css is coming from a textarea as a string how do you tell the SASS API to compress a string?

Comment: As in the example given on the doc page I linked:
`engine = Sass::Engine.new("#main {background-color: #0000ff}", :syntax => :scss, :style => :compressed); engine.render`

Answer (score 2):

How about [Juicer](http://cjohansen.no/en/ruby/juicer_a_css_and_javascript_packaging_tool)?

Comment: By using Juicer I would need to do:
 'juicer install yui_compressor'
That can't be done on heroku

Answer (score 0):

1.Install Ruby and open
2.install gem by entering  ' gem install saas ' press enter.
3.type sass -scss -t compressed 'source file' then 'destinationfile'.

ex- sass -scss -t compressed sass/_theme.scss css/theme.css